# Function select from SQL server

Tags: javascript, sql

I am writing a code like this:

In **dboperations.js**:

```
const config = require('./config');
const sql = require('mssql');

async function get_file(id){
try{
    
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result = await pool.request()
    
    .input('input_id',sql.Int, id)
    .query(`SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ${input_id}`);
  
    return result;
}
catch (error){
    console.log(error);
}
}

module.exports = {
   get_file
}
```

And in **display.js** as below:

```
const dboperation = require('../database/dboperations');

function showitem(id){                    
const display = function(req, res) {
   dboperation.get_file(id).then (result => {    
   console.log(result);
 })
}
}
```

The code **dboperation.js** worked. I am new to JavaScript. At what point am I wrong? It does not show the results.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you *call* the `display` function...?

Comment: I call showitem from <a> tag. I dont know much about JavaScript.

Comment: Right. I said I don't see a call to `display` (not `showitem`). In `showitem`, you create a function you assign to a `display` constant. But you never **call** that function. It's not clear to me why you have that part. If you remove the `const display = ` line and the `}` line that matches it, that code should work. `function showitem(id) { dboperation.get_file(id).then(result => { console.log(result); }); }`

Comment: I try to edit with your advice but it not work. Thank you

Comment: @LeTho, Can you please show us console.log(result) inside function get_file before return result? I don't think it will return a correct result from it.

Comment: It return 
result: [object Object]
but in postman after return result I have this
[
    {
        "title_id": 3660,
        "title": "    V1 5/7 10H  MUOI BINH DINH ",
        "import_title": "    V1 5/7 10H  MUOI BINH DINH ",
        "author": "NGUYENHUNGCUONG",
        "duration": 84831,
        "import_date": "2021-07-06T13:34:04.470Z",
        "file_id": 3660,
        "itemcode_id": 3660,
        "comment": "",
        "keywords": "",
        "is_online": 0
    }
]

Comment: @LeTho, I think you should provide all your all codes including how you call the function in frontend as well. Otherwise, it is hard to help you debug.

Comment: Thanks. But It very simple.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>API Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src='/server/controller/display.js'> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="8089" onClick="showitem(8089)"/>
  </body>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait),

You didn't pass the `id` to the `query()` properly. You should use `@` to pass the variable `input_id`.

Here is the example:

```js
const config = require("./config");
const sql = require("mssql");

async function get_file(id) {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result = await pool
      .request()
      .input("input_id", sql.Int, id)
      .query(`SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = @input_id`);

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  get_file,
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But it work with
router.route('/view/:id').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperation.get_file(request.params.id).then (result => {
    console.log(result);
    response.json(result[0]);
    })
})

Comment: @LeTho, Can you please update your question with the `getBasicSpots`? we don't see this function.